# How To Decode Json Data From Google Geocoding API Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am sending an address string to the google geocoding api in order to obtain that addresses longitude and latitude, however when I get the JSON Data back I'm struggling to decode the JSON data that returns. I am thinking the data should be put into a struct however with the data having different arrays within it I am not sure how to structure this.

Code For Getting The Geocoding Location:

```
func longLatLookUp() {
        
         let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=10+Princes+Street+Edinburgh+Scotland&key={ API key }")!

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
```

Console Returns:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "10",
               "short_name" : "10",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Princes Street",
               "short_name" : "Princes St",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Edinburgh",
               "short_name" : "Edinburgh",
               "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Edinburgh",
               "short_name" : "Edinburgh",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Scotland",
               "short_name" : "Scotland",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
               "short_name" : "GB",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "EH2 2AN",
               "short_name" : "EH2 2AN",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "10 Princes St, Edinburgh EH2 2AN, UK",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 55.95357130000001,
               "lng" : -3.1900314
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 55.95492028029151,
                  "lng" : -3.188682419708498
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 55.95222231970851,
                  "lng" : -3.191380380291502
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJweMPNY7Hh0gRWMp_nlFlOO0",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "XR35+CX Edinburgh, UK",
            "global_code" : "9C7RXR35+CX"
         },
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Paste your JOSN into [quicktyp.io](https://app.quicktype.io) and it will help you learn how to build the structs.

Comment: Thanks! That was a great help and has helped me understand structs and decoding JSON data much better.

Answer (score 2):

#### EDIT:

*plus_code* can be nil, so I changed it to be optional.

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let results: [Component]
    let status: String

    struct Component: Decodable {
        let address_components: [Address]
        let formatted_address: String
        let geometry: Geometry
        let place_id: String
        let plus_code: PlusCode?
        let types: [String]
    }

    struct Address: Decodable {
        let long_name: String
        let short_name: String
        let types : [String]
    }

    struct Geometry: Decodable {
        let location: Location
        let location_type: String
        let viewport: Viewport
    }

    struct Viewport: Decodable {
        let northeast: Location
        let southwest: Location
    }

    struct PlusCode: Decodable {
        let compound_code: String
        let global_code: String
    }

    struct Location: Decodable {
        let lat: Float
        let lng: Float
    }
}
```

You can decode the data like:

```
let json = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Thanks the structure of this struct really helped me! However I needed to add a CodingKeys enum for each one in order for it to work.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! But it’s not supposed to need CodingKeys since all of the property names match the JSON keys.